# How would I go about iterating through each row in a column and keeping a running tally of every substring that comes up? Python

Tags: python, loops, count

Essentially what I am trying to do is go through the "External_Name" column, row by row, and get a count of unique substrings within each string, kind of like .value_counts().

| External_Name | Specialty |
| --- | --- |
| ABMC Hyperbaric Medicine and Wound Care | Hyperbaric/Wound Care |
| ABMC Kaukauna Laboratory Services | Laboratory |
| AHCM Sinai Bariatric Surgery Clinic | General Surgery |
| ........... | ........... |
| n | n |

For example, after running through the first three rows in "External_Name" the output would be something like

| Output | Count |
| --- | --- |
| ABMC | 2 |
| Hyperbaric | 1 |
| Medicine | 1 |
| and | 1 |
| Wound | 1 |
| Care | 1 |

So on and so forth. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split at whitespace with `str.split()`, then `explode` the resulting word lists into individual rows and count the values with `value_counts`.

```py
>>> df.External_Name.str.split().explode().value_counts()
ABMC          2
Hyperbaric    1
Medicine      1
and           1
Wound         1
Care          1
Kaukauna      1
Laboratory    1
Services      1
AHCM          1
Sinai         1
Bariatric     1
Surgery       1
Clinic        1
Name: External_Name, dtype: int64
```